# проблема builtins в Pycharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

При работе в Pycharm с определенного момента появилась проблема, любая функция из `builtins`, такие как `print`, `exit`, `range` и т.д. подчеркиваются красным и предлагается их импортировать из `builtins`. [image: пример ошибки]

Соответственно код`from builtins import *` полностью решает данную проблему для конкретного файла. Т.е. мне нужно каждый раз импортировать `builtins` заново (раньше же этой проблемы не было, значит должно же это все автоматом импортироваться как то)???

Почему-то в IDLE такой проблемы нет, в Atom тоже.

Перерыл весь интернет в поисках решения, самое полное описание [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6102908/how-do-i-get-intellij-to-recognize-common-python-modules), но ничего не помогло. Пробовал даже полностью переустановить Pycharm, соответственно теперь он у меня последней версии "2020.1.2". Windows 10.

Comment: В virtualenv то же самое?

Comment: @вася В нем и происходит эта дичь (https://ibb.co/6rJZk2x)

Comment: Попробуйте новую пустую создать

Comment: @вася создавал, все ровно тоже самое.

Comment: Попробуйте File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart... -> Invalidate and Restart

Comment: @вася Я пробовал, тоже 0 реакций, другими словами я пробовал то, что [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/), а там этот вариант был предложен.

Comment: 2 последних варианта: 1) удалите `__pycache__` или создайте новый проект 2) проверьте, что используете `python3`, а не `python2`

Comment: @вася любой новый проект имеет данную проблему,(__pycache__ удалял и создавал заново)

Comment: Переставьте питон и pycharm...

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica с самого начала ваша идея не понравилась, ибо я уже раза 3 переустановил pycharm, что не помогало. Сейчас удалил вместе с Pycharm также весь питон (интерпретаторы). После чего скинул с ноута старую версию Pycharm(2019.2.2) и питон(3.7.4) после чего все стало на места, обновлять пучарм до последней версии вообще никогда не буду, видимо. 
P.S. спасибо за решение

Comment: Ну я тоже не обновляю до последней... Надо сидеть на stable версиях!

Comment: Можете кстати написать самоответом.

Answer (score 1):

Решение из разряда ты переустанови, оно и заработает:

- Пробовал **удалять чисто Pycharm** несколько раз, ибо так как все остальные среды работали, то видать в нем проблема —  **не помогло**.
- А надо было не только Pycharm удалить, но и все интерпретаторы (библиотеки удалять не пришлось).
  После чего скинул с ноута старую версию Pycharm(2019.2.2) и питон(3.7.4). Bсе стало на места.

P.S. Oбновлять pycharm до последней версии вообще никогда не буду, видимо.